Kubernetes doesn't evict podes from "unplugged" node
We have k8s v1.25.6 on-prem cluster with 3 nodes and a second one as a mirror (it's production setup). On them both we observed that if a node failed the expected eviction of pods that were running on it didn't happen. I've tried to replicate this but on most installations everything works as expected - in 5 minutes every pod gets 'relocated' to a different node. So for almost all clusters everything is fine, except for one where the issue reproduced so things down below are from this testing cluster.
It's v1.27.7 on-prem cluster with 3 nodes.
One node is stopped (manually for a test) and it goes in NotReady state, but pods don't get transferred to any other node even after a couple of hours.
kubectl get nodes                                            
NAME    STATUS     ROLES           AGE   VERSION
node1   Ready      control-plane   84d   v1.27.7
node2   Ready      control-plane   84d   v1.27.7
node3   NotReady   <none>          84d   v1.27.7

node3 has 2 taints:
Taints
node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute

and we have multiple pods on this node in "ready" and some in "terminated" statuses, all stuck in this for hours. They all have pretty standard settings (nothing about eviction policies, taints etc is touched in config), and in describe:
kubectl describe pod <...>
<...>
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
<...>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>

(events here is even funnier because it contained a "node is not ready" warning for first hour)
So in other words - I don't get the expected behavior of "resettling" pods from down node onto other nodes. Not every pod gets stuck like this, some go over whole flow without an issue (while having the same deployment, with no significant difference aside from service image itself and ENV variables)
In events:
kubectl get events
<...>
12m         Warning   NodeNotReady           pod1                Node is not ready
7m33s       Normal    TaintManagerEviction   pod1                Marking for deletion Pod
7m32s       Normal    Scheduled              pod1                Successfully assigned to node1
7m21s       Normal    AddedInterface         pod1                Add eth0 from k8s-pod-network
7m20s       Normal    Pulled                 pod1                Container image on machine
7m20s       Normal    Created                pod1                Created container 
7m20s       Normal    Started                pod1                Started container 
7m32s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate       replicaset/pod2     Created pod
<...>
13m         Warning   NodeNotReady           podA                Node is not ready
8m26s       Normal    TaintManagerEviction   podA                Marking for deletion Pod podA
<...>

basically podA was supposed to get deleted but instead stuck with "Ready" and never got onto the next stage of eviction.
What should I check and look for to get behind the reasons it happens? Other questions I found here were about a problem with eviction settings with older versions of k8s, but it's not the same case here. So I'm lost in game "spot 10 differences" for clusters that are fine and these where the mechanism is broken somehow, and I need advice on where to dig up.

In the cluster where you are experiencing an issue,  how many worker nodes are there?  in the details shared in above post there is only one worker node and other two are master so in that case applications pod wont get scheduled to master nodes,

Nataraj Medayhal
that was my guess at first too, but as shown on the examples - I do have actually pods that were successfully transferred to other nodes, there's no any taints and/or affinities that could've been preventing pods to work on "node1" and "node2". In events I see both cases where pods get stuck ("podA") and get assigned to working node (in example it's simplified "pod1" - it got reassigned and recreated as "pod2").
But yes the point about config of the nodes is valid and this cluster is actually a bit broken, but I need to know what exactly goes wrong so I can target it on prod

In above cluster details which has been shared node1 and node2 are master nodes.  When cluster gets created for master nodes an taint is added by kubeadm as "control-plane: NoSchedule"  which will not allow application pods to be scheduled onto master nodes  only critical workloads which belong to control plane will get scheduled.  More details are in https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#node-role-kubernetes-io-control-plane-taint
